Color range lowered after enabling Nvidia GPU
Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma 5
Hardware: RTX 3050
I have a laptop that has a RTX 3050 GPU and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma. I had previously disabled the RTX 3050 and was running just on Intel graphics. Things looked fine, but I wanted to enable the RTX 3050 in order to get access to it for video rendering and other tasks.
Upon installing the Nvidia drivers from the 'Additional Drivers' software section, I noticed that the displayed colors are now noticeably muted compared to before. I've tried both the 535 and 545 drivers with no difference. In doing research, it turns out that Nvidia often sets the color range to 'Limited' by default instead of the 'Full' which would explain why the colors are muted.
I've found an image of portion of the control panel that should allow the user to change the color range from 'Limited' to 'Full,' but this portion of the control panel doesn't exist on my installation.
https://imgur.com/PxBqn5L
Does anyone have any advice on how to fix the limited color range issue?
Thanks for any help!

As further clarification, this page explains what Limited and Full mean for the color range.
https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/full-rgb-vs-limited-rgb-is-there-a-difference.html
